# how to update cells in col by mergin two data frames?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 data frames.

df1 has lots of columns and among those columns I also have date, ccy, baseCcy and xchRts
df2 has only date, ccy, baseCcy and xchRts

I want to upadate the xchRts column in df1 with values from df2

`pd.merge(df1, df2, how="left", on=['date', 'baseCcy', 'ccy'])`

the operation creates xchRts_x and xchRts_y
I don't want this to happen.
I want values in xchRts to be overwritten if they exist in df2.

Answer (score 0):

Described behaviour is correct. If you want have values from 'xchRts' df2 just remove in df1 column 'xchRts' or rename.

```
df1 = df1.drop(columns=["xchRts"])
pd.merge(df1, df2, how="left", on=['date', 'baseCcy', 'ccy'])
```

Comment: i don't want this. i want to keep the column because there are other values in that column that i need

Comment: In this case you should create a function which implements the necessary logic because pandas does not know which value to leave and which need to overwrite df1['xchRts'] = df1.apply(your_function, df2=df2, axis=1)

Comment: If your original answer does not answer the question, you should put the changes as an edit to your answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Add a step using [combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)：

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="left", on=['date', 'baseCcy', 'ccy'])
df1['xchRts'] = df3['xchRts_y'].combine_first(df3['xchRts_x'])
```